# How to display all wp theme layouts

Tags: wordpress

I created a theme and want to display all my layouts for the buyer to check them out .
look
http://khositeweb.com/preview/aktina/blog/
hover on the blog in the menu, you can see all layouts . 
so can you tell how to create one of those pages so I can display one layout that is different from the index page ?
I have all layouts I just need to show them all
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create different templates of your layouts.Then Create new different pages you want to show people choosing your different layouts templates to each page.After creation of pages show it in Menu.